# In banach algebra: Show there exists $x$ s.t. $x^2+bx+xb+c=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a banach algebra with unit $e$ and $b,c\in A$ be such that $\sigma(b^2-c)\subset \mathbb{R}^+$

Then there exists $x\in A$ such that $$x^2+bx+xb+c=0$$

I want to show this, but lack the insight to proceed

The only thing we got is $(b^2-c-\lambda e )$ is invertible for some $\lambda < 0$

so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm rusty on my functional analysis, but if you complete the square, you see that you want $x$ so that $(x+b)^2 - b^2 + c = 0,$ or $(x+b)^2 = b^2 - c$. Now, the taylor series for the function $\sqrt{x}$ will converge uniformly on $\sigma(b^2 - c)$, since it is a compact subset of the positive reals, and you can construct a sequence of polynomials in the Banach algebra that build $\sqrt{b^2 - c}$ for you. Then subtract $b$ to get $x$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see how we construct $\sqrt{b^2-c}$. Why does the Taylor series of $\sqrt{x} $ converge on $\sigma(b^2-c)$...?

Comment: @DinkyDoe You need to read more on functional calculus in Banach algebras to understand construction of $\sqrt{b^2-c}$

Comment: I think so yes. I'm reading chapter 10 from Rudin about banach - algebra's where they talk about in which cases one can define functions f(z) on A. In fact Theorem 10.30 also gives the answer: If $A$ is a Banach algebra, $x\in A$ and the spectrum $\sigma(x)$ does not seperate 0 from $\infty$ then $x$ has roots of all orders. So it would follow from direct application of this Theorem.